# Highcharts - Unable to see all labels on the bar charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

All the labels on the x-Axis of the chart are not visible, I can see that the chart correctly populating, the tool tip also shows correct xAxis point.

All I want is each and every label on the x-Axis should appear. I am creating a BAR graph.

Example graph - http://jsfiddle.net/HsLCn/

See the miss category label on x-axis.

```
series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [[3,5], [1,3], [0,4], [2,7], [4,2]]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [[2,5], [1,3], [0,4], [3,7], [4,2]]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [[3,5], [1,3], [0,4], [2,7], [4,2]]
        }]
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you post your chart code, or provide a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Hi Steve, here is the example - http://jsfiddle.net/HsLCn/

Comment: Interesting. I would expect the step labels option to sort it if set to 1, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please take look at crop option, which probably is a reason of your problem

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.crop

EDIT:
xAxis labels are not displayed, because data is not sorted by x, ascending

http://jsfiddle.net/HsLCn/3/

```
 series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [[0,4],[1,3],[2,7],[3,5],[4,2]]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [[0,4],[1,3],[2,5], [3,7], [4,2]]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [ [0,4],[1,3], [2,7],[3,5], [4,2]]
        }]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response but the problem I am facing with x-axis tick interval labels. see this example - http://jsfiddle.net/HsLCn/

Comment: Becuase legend overlap datalabel, so you need to set legend in other position.

Comment: I think the problem is with the x-axis categories not all showing. Only 3 out of 5 categories are shown on the x-axis.

Comment: I believe it is not related to sorting alone, I have sorted the data but the problem still persists. One thing I noticed is when there are equal no. of data points it works and when the other way meaning one or more of the series has only one data point  basically less than the max the problem comes back.

Comment: Please send me updated example, if it is possible, with sorted data and your isse